# DBA - SQL Server 2005 - Backups

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup

I am trying to figure out how SQL Server DBAs are doing their backups and verify in 2005. I use the Idera's free stored procs (which is no longer available to download btw) to backup and verify and have gotten around 65% compression. If there any other free alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what Idera's scripts do, but you could script a (native) SQL backup to a temporary location, then call PKZip or 7zip or some command-line compression software to compress the backup to a permanent storage location.

Note that most of these zip utilities have a high CPU cost.

See the discussion in the comments of this post:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/our-backup-strategy-inexpensive-nas/

(Edit: Or just upgrade to SQL2008 R2, which supports native backup compression.)

Answer (score 1):

The Idera which you are using an 3rd party tool , with that tool it can be backup/restore & you can monitor for your server & databases..

As you asked the question-
 am trying to figure out how SQL Server DBAs are doing their backups and verify in 2005. I use the Idera's free stored procs (which is no longer available to download btw) to backup and verify and have gotten around 65% compression. If there any other free alternative?

> > SQL server has it's own native tool where you can set up your backup of databases to go disk,
> >     usually with the SSIS packages by using Maitenace plan (or)T-sql(where you can configure Full,differntial and log backup also)(where after backup finish you can check the verify integrity of the backup) but if the database grows more and more then you may need to ensre about the capcity as this goes to disk(here you need cut the backup stragegy for big database say 1TB bcz usually for Big database taking full daily causes lot of I/O then you have to decide weekly full backup along with the other days differntial backup in place) & you should do the cleanup also for howmany days you want(in the same maintenace plan only it exists).

see for ex-http://bradmcgehee.com/2010/01/13/how-to-use-sql-backup-inside-a-maintenance-plan/

but the backup/restore totally depends on how well you manage from your side by knowing the business risk & communincated with them.

In sql server 2008 onwards you have backup compression like how the Idera sql safe does.

But the Backup usually depends on what they have Implemented whether from the Native tool or from any other 3rd part like Commvault,Idera,TDP(goes to tape) etc...  it depeds on what is agreed for.

Backup-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Free (good) SQL Server DBA tools are hard to find. = /

Have you considered Windows Backups?

It's definitely not the best thing out there, and it takes up a lot of space, but it is free, it does backup your data, and you already have it installed.